# ios--When the system displays high-quality pictures

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

In my app, I am using the iPhone 6 simulator and xcode 4.6. I've added a background imageView to my app, Here I have two pictures, myPic.png(320*480) and myPic@2x.png(640*960), But the system only displays the myPic.png pictures when the system displays high-quality pictures.
Can anyone tell me,thanks!

Comment: change device from hardware->Device->iPhone Ratina then it will use myPic@2x.png image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your project on retina display than it will display that 2x image instead small image. and for that you have to write your code like this.

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 17, 30, 30)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPic"];
```

Dont write extension of image so it will display image according to your screen.

Comment: But I App run  on the iphone5, it only shown the non-HD mode picture

Comment: Can you show your code that display image and plz check that HD image is added in bundle not referenced.

Comment: Thank you, I set simulator on the display HD mode, i can see the high-definition picture,